A three-eye monster or a three-eyed monster?
A lesson lasting for three hours is a three-hour lesson, but apparently, a monster that has three eyes is a three-eyed monster.
When should I add -ed after the noun in a compound adjective?

Your question has been asked several times in the past. It doesn't mean it's a weak question or that it is unhelpful but... it's been answered several times. Related: A three room house but a three headED dog and Why is it that a noun can be added with -ed?

An answer listing expressions with the past particle: Most spiders are eight-eyed.

It's always the green-eyed monster, but pheasants are as likely to be ring neck as ring necked.
